# Child element is not populating from XSL file

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

When I add static value to the parent tag, grandChild tag is not populating with template match

I have tried template-match and for-each to encounter the problem
Input:

```
<VocabularyList>
    <Vocabulary>
        <VocabularyElementList>
            <VocabularyElement>
                <Number>1234674</Number>
            </VocabularyElement>
            <VocabularyElement>
                <Number>1234675</Number>
            </VocabularyElement>
        </VocabularyElementList>
    </Vocabulary>
</VocabularyList>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="VocabularyList/Vocabulary">
    <Vocabulary type="abc:def:ijk:Location"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="VocabularyList/Vocabulary/VocabularyElementList/VocabularyElement/Number">
    <VocabularyElement id="abc:def:ijk:{substring(.,1,15)}"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Header/Data/VocabularyList/Vocabulary">
    <Vocabulary type="abc:def:ijk:Location">
            <xsl:element name="VocabularyElementList">
                <xsl:element name="VocabularyElement">
                    <xsl:for-each select ="VocabularyElement/Number">
                        <VocabularyElement id="abc:def:ijk:{substring(.,1,15)}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
    </Vocabulary>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected Output:

```
<VocabularyList>
    <Vocabulary type="abc:def:ijk:Location">
        <VocabularyElementList>
            <VocabularyElement id="abc:def:ijk:1234674">
                <attribute id="abc:def:ijk#name">Company One</attribute>
            </VocabularyElement>
            <VocabularyElement id="abc:def:ijk:1234675">
                <attribute id="abc:def:ijk#name">Company Two</attribute>
            </VocabularyElement>
        </VocabularyElementList>
    </Vocabulary>
</VocabularyList>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

What you have missed is that template rules are not applied automagically, they are invoked to process nodes that are selected using an xsl:apply-templates instruction. For a better understanding of the template rule mechanism, you need to do some further reading. My own preference is always to buy a decent textbook, but if you prefer unstructured online reading you could start with [Can't stop thinking about XSLT in procedural terms... help with apply-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333463/cant-stop-thinking-about-xslt-in-procedural-terms-help-with-apply-templates/334817#334817).

Start by changing the first two template rules to

```
<xsl:template match="Vocabulary">
    <Vocabulary type="abc:def:ijk:Location">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Vocabulary>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Number">
    <VocabularyElement id="abc:def:ijk:{substring(.,1,15)}">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </VocabularyElement>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that I've also simplified the match patterns. There's no need to provide the full context of an element like Number in the match pattern unless it appears in different contexts and you want to apply different rules depending on the context.